# Problems with ORMLite and lazy collections

Tags: android, collections, ormlite, foreign-collection

I am using ormlite in my android project. I have two classes

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "usershows")
public class UserShow {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer showId;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<Episode> episodes;
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "episodes")
public class Episode {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer episodeId;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private UserShow show;
    ...
}
```

I am saving my UserShows objects like [in example](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-jdbc/trunk/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreignCollection/)

```
UserShow show = new UserShow();
userShowDao.create(show);

for (Episode e: eps) {
    e.setShow(show);
    episodeDao.create(e); 
}
```

UserShow object have a foreign lazy collection episodes, but when I am trying to get all userShows:

```
shows = userShowsDao().queryForAll();
```

I am getting all shows objects with collections of episodes. Why this happens? Collection is lazy and I must to get null or something else but no collection of Episode object. How to make this collection really lazy? It may be cool if ORMLite have ability get objects without lazy collections and initialize when it really need. For example as `Hibernate.initialize` method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lazy collections have been well tested and are in use by many others so although there could be bugs with it, it is more likely that you are being tricked by the lazy collection class.

When each of the `UserShow` objects is retrieved from the DAO, the `episodes` will not be null but instead will be set with an instance of `LazyForeignCollection`.  However, no additional queries will be made and there will be no `Episode` data contained by the collection.  If you then make a call to one of the methods on the collection such as `userShow.getEpisodes().iterator()`, then a *separate* query is made at that time to allow you to iterate through that show's episodes.  That's how the lazy collections work.

If you still think that the lazy collections aren't working then please show us how you are determining that the shows have episode data.  To see what queries are being done where, you can enable [Android logging with ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging).

---

**Edit:**

It turns out that @Georgy was using the debugger to investigate the collection.  The debugger is most likely calling the same `iterator()` or `toArray()` methods which cause the collection queries to be issued at that instant.  So there weren't any episodes in the collection before the debugger asked for them.

Comment: Gray, thanks for reply. I am getting userShows objects with initialized collections of episodes, however I do not make any calls to episodes.

Comment: I can see this in my debugger http://postimage.org/image/cdqihamc/ method 
public List<UserShow> getAllUserShows() {
        List<UserShow> shows = null;
        try {
            shows = getHelper().getUserShowsDao().queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return shows;
    }

Comment: Yeah, your debugger is calling the `iterator()` and the other methods that make the query at that point.  It is showing that there are episodes there but they _weren't_ there before the debugger asked for them.  If you turn on logging you should be able to see the query being hit only when the debugger shows you information about the collection.

Comment: I beleive you, but I want to check and to see rinning sql queries. Do you know how to enable sql logging in ormlite or sqlite. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you do _not_ believe me.  :-)  See the online docs: http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging

Comment: Gray I checked it and you right! Thank you very much for good explanation. Debugger really makes additional call and trying to get episodes from separate table. If I not using debbugger there are no additional queries. Gray, good work!

Answer (score 1):

Your example should be OK. I created the relevant test tables and inserted 2 `usershows` and 3 `episodes`. I then tailed the MySQL log (set by running MySQL with `--general-log=<log file name>` - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html).

Full test Groovy script:

```
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager
import com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource
cs = new JdbcConnectionSource('jdbc:mysql://localhost/episode?user=root')
epDao = DaoManager.createDao(cs,Episode)
usDao = DaoManager.createDao(cs,UserShow)
usDao.queryForAll().each { println it }
```

Log shows only one select statement ran:

```
110830 13:11:09     1 Query SELECT * FROM `usershows`
```

Change the last line to the following (which iterates over all usershows and gets the episodes field for each one:

```
usDao.queryForAll().each { println it.episodes }
```

Results in:

```
110830 13:15:31     1 Query SELECT * FROM `usershows`
                    1 Query SELECT * FROM `episodes` WHERE `show_id` = 1
                    1 Query SELECT * FROM `episodes` WHERE `show_id` = 2
```

Comment: Unk, thanks for your reply. As I can see in your example, episodes gets on demand. But in my project when I get usetShows objects and have no any calls to episodes I get also episodes anyway. I can see this in debbuger. How I can get usershows without episodes?

Comment: I imagine the debugger forces the episodes to be retrieved? That is, as the ForeignCollection interface is a java.util.Collection and Iterable, the debugger knows how to look at the contents; as soon as it does, it triggers the episodes to be retrieved from the database.

Comment: It very strange behavior if this true. With hibernate behavior is different, debbuger explictly says that collection is lazy and have no ways to get it force.